# How to call C's fread() function in Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, callback, fread, ffi

I have a C code with me which I need to covert to Ruby code.
Here is the C code for your reference.

```
    //bundle_ingest.h
    typedef void
    (* bundle_read_fn)(
        gsdk_void_t*    callback_data,
        gsdk_byte_t*    buffer,
        gsdk_size_t     buffer_size,
        gsdk_size_t*    p_bytes_read,
        gsdk_bool_t*    abort
        );

    gsdk_error_t bundle_ingest(
        gsdk_void_t*            callback_data,
        bundle_read_fn          bundle_read_fn
        );

    //main.c
    void bundle_read_callback(
        gsdk_void_t*    callback_data,
        gsdk_byte_t*    buffer,
        gsdk_size_t buffer_size,
        gsdk_size_t*    p_bytes_read,
        gsdk_bool_t*    abort
        )
    {
        if((callback_data == NULL) || (buffer == NULL) || (p_bytes_read == NULL))
        {
            *abort = TRUE;
            return;
        }

        *p_bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, buffer_size, (FILE *)callback_data);
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE             *fp = NULL;
        gsdk_error_t     error = GSDK_SUCCESS;

        fp = fopen("mybundle.b", "rb");

        //1. this call invokes the bundle_read_callback function
        //2. definition of bundle_ingest() is in bundle_ingest.dll which I am linking
        //
        error = bundle_ingest((void *)fp, bundle_read_callback); 

        //if error = 0, I get the desired file generated in my current working folder.
        return 0;   
    }
```

MY QUESTION: I want to implement the same piece code in Ruby. 
I have written all the code in Ruby except that of the 'fread' call in the callback function. 
Can anyone provide me the direction or the solution of the alternate call to C's fread() function in Ruby. FYI, I have tried 'ffi-libc' already but that's not working for me.

Note: I am using FFI for calling C functions in my Ruby.
Here is the Ruby code for your reference.

```
    module Bundle

            FFI.add_typedef(:pointer, :GsdkCallbacksS)

            callback :bundle_read_fn, [ :pointer, :pointer, :gsdk_size_t, :pointer, :pointer ], :void

            class GsdkCallbacksS < FFI::Struct
              layout(
                      :callback_fpbundle_read, :bundle_read_fn
                    )
            end

            attach_function :bundle_ingest, [ :pointer, :bundle_read_fn ], :gsdk_error_t
    end

    class Ingestion

        include Bundle

        BundleReadCallback = Proc.new do | callback_data, buffer, buffer_size, p_bytes_read, abort|

        puts "\ninside BundleReadCallback\n\n"

        if((callback_data == nil) or (buffer == nil) || (p_bytes_read == nil))
            abort.wtire_pointer(true)
          return
        end
        ##################################################################################
        ## TODO: Ruby alternate to C's fread()                                          ##
        ## C call: *p_bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, buffer_size, (FILE *)callback_data);##
        ##################################################################################
        end 

        def ingest_bundle (bundlle_file)

         callback = GsdkCallbacksS.new
         callback[:callback_fpbundle_read] = BundleReadCallback

         size = File.size(bundle_file)
           open(bundle_file, "rb") do |io|
            fp = io.read(size)
            error = bundle_ingest(fp, callback[:callback_fpbundle_read])
            puts "bundle_ingest, error = #{error}"
            io.close
          end
        end
    end

    ### Ruby main.rb

    bi = Ingestion.new

    bi.ingest_bundle("mybundle.b")
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to fread(3) in Ruby is [IO#read.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read)

Btw, the equivalent to read(2) in Ruby is [IO#sysread.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-sysread)